# Find button based on content

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

```
 <StackPanel Name="stTeam2" Width="40" >
     <Button Click="Team2_Click"  Height="55" Name="btn1T2" Width="30">T1</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn2T2" Width="30">T2</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn3T2" Width="30">T3</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn4T2" Width="30">T4</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn5T2" Width="30">T5</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn6T2" Width="30">T6</Button>
     <Button Click="Team2_Click" Height="55" Name="btn7T2" Width="30">T7</Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

Is it possible to find the Button control Based on content.

If T5 is specified can we find the control btn5T2 in the stackpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can...Although entirely inefficient way to develop WPF software. 
Since you gave your StackPanel a name in the XAML you can  access it from the Code-Behind

#### Code Behind

```
for (int i = 0; i < stTeam2.Children.Count; i++)
{
    if (stTeam2.Children[i].GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        Button currentButton = (Button)stTeam2.Children[i];
        if (currentButton.Content.ToString().Equals("T4"))
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me is there any better way to go about this. VisualTreeHelper will not work as it finds elements on name

Answer (score 1):

Of course, by Visual Tree (VisualTreeHelper class) you could find each elements and you could check its content.

OR for panel, you could loop the child elements via its Panel.Children property.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to MyKuLLSKI's answer, but using LINQ:

```
var matchingButton = stTeam2.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(
                         btn => btn.Content.ToString().Equals("T5")).FirstOrDefault();
```